# inappsettingskit initially works but after 1-2 days returns null when reading settings

Tags: ios

When using iphone app with inappsettingskit reading the settings values begin returning null after 1-2 days. It appears to work fine initially, preferences save and load without problems. After some time of using the app, seems to be 1 or 2 days, the preferences cannot be read anymore and return null. Here is how I read them:

```
NSString *subjectValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"email_subject"];
```

This works fine and returns what I want but then after one or two days it starts returning null.

Comment: did you try like this?? [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"email_subject"];

Comment: There is not enough information here for anybody to help you. The idea that it stops working after a certain amount of time has passed is strange. Can you update your question and provide more info, list things that you've tried, etc.?

Comment: If you have saved a value for the key email_subject in NSUserDefaults, the only reason I can think of that it would return nil would be if you had deleted and reinstalled your app. Or maybe if the value that you saved there is a different type from what you're trying to retrieve (i.e., you saved an NSNumber as the object for that key but are trying to retrieve an NSString.